# Using VBScript to return ipv4 addresses as variables

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am trying to use `.Exec` to pull back the IP configuration of a machine. From the given output of the command I then want to return all the wireless and Ethernet LAN IPv4 addresses or "media disconnected" if not present. I am pretty stuck on how to approach this as users can often have multiple NIC's. I can get the output however I am not sure how to iterate through the results of the `ipconfig` to store the information I need.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
StrIPConfig = "ipconfig /all"
Set IPConfig = objShell.Exec(StrIPConfig)

strText = ""

Do While Not IPConfig.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = IPConfig.StdOut.Readline
    If InStr(strText, "Wireless Network Connection") Then
        strWLAN = IPConfig.StdOut.Readline +2
        WScript.Echo strWLAN
    End If
Loop

Do While Not IPConfig.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = IPConfig.StdOut.Readline
    If InStr(strText, "Local Area Connection") Then
        strLAN = IPConfig.StdOut.Readline +2
        WScript.Echo strWLAN
    End If
Loop
```

Has to be done via WMI Windows batch file or WMI VBscript or VBScript using `Exec` as above. PowerShell, unfortunately, is not an option.

Comment: Using `wmic` to perform a WMI query returning just the information you need is likely to be easier than parsing the output of `ipconfig`.See http://serverfault.com/a/55437/1440

Answer (score 0):

Use [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974579.aspx) (specifically the [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217.aspx) class) instead of shelling out:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmgts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True"

For Each nic In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  For Each addr In nic.IPAddress
    WScript.Echo addr
  Next
Next
```

Comment: There's a typo: it's `winmgmts` not `winmgmgts`.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted an answer from another forum, using a WMI script wrapped by VBScript. It is currently storing the information as a string however it will be easy enough to adapt now:

```
strWLAN = ""
strLAN = ""
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set IPAdapterSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select AdapterType, NetConnectionID, MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID LIKE 'Wireless network%'")


For Each IPConfig in IPAdapterSet
 Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select IPEnabled, Description, Caption, IPAddress, MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled='True' AND MACAddress = '" & IPConfig.MACAddress & "' ")
   For Each IPConf in IPConfigSet
    if NOT strWLAN="" then
      strWLAN = strWLAN & vbCrLf
    end if
    strWLAN = strWLAN  & " " & IPConfig.NetConnectionID & " "
    If Not IsNull(IPConf.IPAddress) Then
     For i = LBound(IPConf.IPAddress) to UBound(IPConf.IPAddress)
      If Not ((Instr(IPConf.IPAddress(i), ":") > 0) or (Instr(IPConf.IPAddress(i), "none") > 0)) Then
    if i=0 then
      strWLAN = strWLAN & " " & IPConf.IPAddress(i)
    else
      strWLAN = strWLAN & ", " & IPConf.IPAddress(i) 
    end if
      End If
     Next
    End If
   next
Next



Set objWMIService2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set IPAdapterSet2 = objWMIService2.ExecQuery("Select AdapterType, NetConnectionID, MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID LIKE 'Local Area Connection%'")


For Each IPConfig in IPAdapterSet2
 Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select IPEnabled, Description, Caption, IPAddress, MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled='True' AND MACAddress = '" & IPConfig.MACAddress & "' ")
   For Each IPConf in IPConfigSet
    if NOT strLAN="" then
      strLAN = strLAN & vbCrLf
    end if
    strLAN = strLAN  & " " & IPConfig.NetConnectionID & " "
    If Not IsNull(IPConf.IPAddress) Then
     For i = LBound(IPConf.IPAddress) to UBound(IPConf.IPAddress)
      If Not ((Instr(IPConf.IPAddress(i), ":") > 0) or (Instr(IPConf.IPAddress(i), "none") > 0)) Then
    if i=0 then
      strLAN = strLAN & " " & IPConf.IPAddress(i)
    else
      strLAN = strLAN & ", " & IPConf.IPAddress(i) 
    end if
      End If
     Next
    End If
   next
Next


wscript.Echo strWLAN
wscript.Echo strLAN
```